# Using DBMS_PASSTHROUGH to create SQL Server aliases from Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have an Oracle database with a dblink that connects to a SQL Server database.  From Oracle, I try to create a SQL Server login and alias like this:

```
declare
   l_num_rows number;
begin
  l_num_rows := dbms_hs_passthrough.execute_immediate@MYDBLINK ('CREATE LOGIN [John.Smith] WITH PASSWORD =  ''B!gdaddy12''');
  commit;
  execute immediate 'alter session close database link MYDBLINK';
  commit;
  l_num_rows := dbms_hs_passthrough.execute_immediate@MYDBLINK ('USE Testdb; exec sp_addalias [John.Smith], [HONCHO3]');
  commit;
  execute immediate 'alter session close database link MYDBLINK';
  commit;
end;
```

What happens is that the login gets created but the alias does not - with no exception being raised.   If I try to create the alias twice as below it does work, i.e. a login and an alias are created:

```
declare
   l_num_rows number;
begin
  l_num_rows := dbms_hs_passthrough.execute_immediate@MYDBLINK ('CREATE LOGIN [John.Smith] WITH PASSWORD =  ''B!gdaddy12''');
  commit;
  execute immediate 'alter session close database link MYDBLINK';
  commit;
  l_num_rows := dbms_hs_passthrough.execute_immediate@MYDBLINK ('USE Testdb; exec sp_addalias [John.Smith], [HONCHO3]');
  commit;
  execute immediate 'alter session close database link MYDBLINK';
  commit;
  l_num_rows := dbms_hs_passthrough.execute_immediate@MYDBLINK ('USE Testdb; exec sp_addalias [John.Smith], [HONCHO3]');
  commit;
  execute immediate 'alter session close database link MYDBLINK';
  commit;
end;
```

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you used SQL Profiler to trace the TSQL being sent to the server? And which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: No , I don't know how to use SQL Profiler to do that, can you pls explain?  I am using SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Profiler,this is a tool that sqlserver support.it's easy,but only a GUI,you can find how to use DMV -> sys.traces,and so on.